# Map XML String to SAP PI Data Type

Tags: xml, sap-pi

I am consuming a SOAP WebService using SAP PI.

The webservice response returns a XML which contains a XML raw string. Something like this:

```xml
<WSResponse xmlns='http://example.com/' xmlns:soap='http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/' xmlns:xsd='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema' xmlns:xsi='http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance'>
  <WSResult>
    &#60;ITEM&#62;&#60;DESC&#62;Example One&#60;/DESC&#62;&#60;/ITEM&#62;&#60;ITEM&#62;&#60;DESC&#62;Example Two&#60;/DESC&#62;&#60;/ITEM&#62;
  </WSResult>
</WSResponse>
```

> &#60 &#62 are the escaped characters <>

Now I want to use the graphical mapping to get the raw string and parse it to the PI XML Data Type like follows:

[image: SAP PI Data Type]

I have tried with replace functions and *return as XML* option...but I am not able to get the desired output.

EDIT: I am also trying with XSLT Mapping, but I am struggling too.

Comment: I am also trying with XSLT Mapping, but I am struggling too

Comment: I merged your comment into your question. You may delete your comment.